# How Can i retrive the attribute value of a checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can we retrieve the attribute values of a checkbox using javascript.

I am using a javascript function in `onclick()` event.

In that function i can able to identify the checkbox is checked or not.

But when i access to retrive value,i didn't get.

```
var id=$("#chkbox").attr("attibteid");
```

The above query wont return anything. Please suggest

Comment: This should work.  Is the checkbox a web forms server control with an ID of chkbox?  If so, that's probably not the actual ID it gets in the DOM and therefore $("#chkbox") won't match anything.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell exactly what you are looking for here, in general if you have a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       id="mycheckbox" 
       value="something" 
       attibteid="custom" 
       data-msg="hello" />
```

and you click on a button to look at it

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="I check checkbox" />
```

then here are values you can check

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
 var $checkbox = $("#mycheckbox");
 var theValue = $checkbox.val();//"something"
 var theId = $checkbox[0].id;//"mycheckbox"
 var isChecked = $checkbox.is(":checked");//false or true
 var attrValue = $checkbox.attr("attibteid");//"custom"
 var someData = $checkbox.data("msg");//"hello"
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TpG5r/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `value` of a checkbox like this:

```
var value = $("#chkbox").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do get the check box status through the click event with `$(this).is(":checked")` but are unable to get it with `$("#chkbox").is(":checked")`, verify that:

- The checkbox has an attribute `id` with the value `chkbox`,
- That there are no other elements with the same `id`.

If you're looking not for the check status, but a value of an attribute, just do:

```
$("#chkbox").attr("<name here>")
```

where you replace "<name here>" by the actual name of the attribute you're looking for.